# Row-wise linear imputation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

I have a data frame with time-series features. I want to impute missing values with row-wise linear imputation.

As a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(2), 
                   'F1_Date_1': [1,2], 
                   'F1_Date_2': [np.nan,4], 
                   'F1_Date_3': [3, 6],
                   'F1_Date_4': [4,8], 
                   'F2_Date_1': [2,11], 
                   'F2_Date_2': [6, np.nan], 
                   'F2_Date_3': [10, np.nan],
                   'F2_Date_4': [14, 17]})
df

   id  F1_Date_1  F1_Date_2  ...  F2_Date_2  F2_Date_3  F2_Date_4
0   0          1        NaN  ...        6.0       10.0         14
1   1          2        4.0  ...        NaN        NaN         17
```

For F1, I want to linearly impute (interpolate) `F1_Date_2` using `F1_Date_1` and `F1_Date_3`. For F2, I want to impute `F2_Date_2` and `F2_Date_3` using `F2_Date_1` and `F2_Date_4`

The desired output is

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(2), 
                   'F1_Date_1': [1,2], 
                   'F1_Date_2': [2,4], 
                   'F1_Date_3': [3, 6],
                   'F1_Date_4': [4,8], 
                   'F2_Date_1': [2,11], 
                   'F2_Date_2': [6, 13], 
                   'F2_Date_3': [10, 15],
                   'F2_Date_4': [14, 17]})

   id  F1_Date_1  F1_Date_2  ...  F2_Date_2  F2_Date_3  F2_Date_4
0   0          1          2  ...          6         10         14
1   1          2          4  ...         13         15         17
```

How can I do that on a very large dataset (potentially 10 million rows, 8 dates, and 15 features) efficiently in Python?

Comment: what do you replace your missing value with exacty ?

Comment: Thank you @mrCopiCat, basically it is a predicted value from linear time-trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` per columns - values before `_` like `F1, F2` with custom function for interpolate:

```
df = (df.set_index('id')
        .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
        .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(axis=1)))

print (df)
    F1_Date_1  F1_Date_2  F1_Date_3  F1_Date_4  F2_Date_1  F2_Date_2  \
id                                                                     
0         1.0        2.0        3.0        4.0        2.0        6.0   
1         2.0        4.0        6.0        8.0       11.0       13.0   

    F2_Date_3  F2_Date_4  
id                        
0        10.0       14.0  
1        15.0       17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by melting, interpolating and 'unmelting' the dataframe.

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["id"])
df = df.groupby(df['variable'].str[:2]).apply(lambda g: g.interpolate()).pivot_table(index='id', columns='variable', values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Thank you @Jinter, but is it an efficient way do it with 10 million rows, 8 dates, and 15 features. Becaue when you melt the data frame it becomes very large. Is there any column-wise way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to do **row-wise** interpolation:

```py
final_df = df.interpolate(axis=1)
```

There is no need to explicitly distinguish between the F1 and the F2 parts if the outmost columns in each part, i.e. `F1_Date_1`, `F1_Date_4`, `F2_Date_1`, and `F2_Date_4` do not contain any missing values.

Comment: OP need `For F1, I want to linearly impute (interpolate) F1_Date_2 using F1_Date_1 and F1_Date_3. For F2, I want to impute F2_Date_2 and F2_Date_3 using F2_Date_1 and F2_Date_4`

Comment: @jezrael I added a sentence explaining why that is the same thing, at least for the given example.